# Proving that matrix is similar to its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

One way to prove that a matrix and its transpose are similar is to apply polynomial matrix theory.

I wonder if there is another way to do that. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "polynomial matrix theory"?

Comment: @carmichael,  I mean the theory of invariant polynomials

Comment: @Matteo,  what if there is not such a canonical Jordan, for example when the field is  not close?

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to do it is to prove that $A$ and $A^t$ have the same Jordan canonical form. In turn, you can prove this showing that for all $\lambda$ and for all $n$

$(A-\lambda I)^n $   and $ (A^T-\lambda I)^n$ have the same rank.

Comment: Sorry,  closed I mean...